# How to order by nearest float value

Tags: mysql

My MySQL table:

```
id | NUMER
1  | 1.233
2  | 4.233
3  | 5.123
4  | 1.146
```

`float` value is **5.4554**

and I need to select rows from above table with order by nearest NUMBER to my float value

Example output:

```
5.123
4.233
1.233 
1.146
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75928b/4)**

Comment: What about limiting your search to entries where NUMER is less than (or equal to) your value, and ordering the results in a descending order?

Comment: Shouldn't 1.233 come before 1.146? Isn't it closer to 5.4554?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
order by abs(numer - float)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from Table1
order by SUBSTRING(NUMER,
          Locate(NUMER ,'.', 1)+3,
                          length(NUMER))
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c9f4/31)**

AFTER **`31`** Attempts I finally got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @floatValue := 5.4554;
SELECT   id, NUMER
FROM     Table
ORDER BY ABS(@floatValue - NUMER)
```

Just order by the difference between the two.  `5.4554-5.123` is ~`0.3`, where as `5.4554-1.146` is ~`4`. (Although i think your demo may be off, shouldn't `1.233` come before `1.146`?)

Anyways, [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e82d37/3/0).

[image: screenshot of query]

Comment: @jasne: what's the problem? They are ordered by closest to `2.4554` to farthest.

Comment: ok , i sloved !! 

example query:     SELECT * FROM customer_trader where rate > 1.3444 ORDER BY abs(`rate` - 1.3444) ASC

Comment: Correct, if you only one one direction you add a `>@floatValue` or `<@floatValue` (depending on which you prefer) other yes, you will get numbers by proximity, direction notwithstanding.